# pandas.to_json - Stop values being converted to String

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying read CSV and  convert to_json using pandas.... the issue I am facing is the values are printed with "".

```
df = pd.read_csv("./xyz.csv")
df.fillna("", inplace=True)
json1 = df.to_json(orient="records")
print(json1)
```

Actual output

```
{"a" : {"b": "c"} }
```

Expected output

```
{"a" : {"b": "c"} }
```

Comment: One way found is :      dict1= df.to_dict(orient="records")
    for dict1_ in dict1:
        print(str(dict1_).replace('"', "").replace("'", '"'))

Comment: Dear @MritiYogan could you please revise your question? I might be incorrectly change the expected output. If thats the case then could you please re-edit? Thanks